# Rails, Posting to a Custom Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my group controller I have two methods:

```
  def new
    @group = Group.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def new_beta
    @group = Group.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I have a form that starts like so:

```
 <%= form_for Group.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

How can I get the form_for to post to the new_beta controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is bad practice but..

in your routes add

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    get :new_beta
    post :new_beta_create
  end
end
```

Now

```
 <%= form_for Group.new, :url => new_beta_create_groups_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

However I recommend creating a new controller called something like:  alternate_groups_controller.  Even better make a namespace for them.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can set :

```
 <%= form_for Group.new, :url=>{ :action =>"new_beta", :controller =>
"group"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

(you can also -preferably- directly use a named route instead of ":url => ")

Comment: must have been the comma, try again.